# How do I tell Diablo 3 I no longer want a key binding?

Tags: diablo-iii

I started up Diablo 3 today for the first time. A few friends were already on it, and I figured, what the hey. Why not. We use Mumble to chat back and forth, so the first thing I wanted to do was make sure nothing else was on my preferred Push-to-talk key.

[image: Diablo 3 Key Bindings - V defaults to "Show Monster Health Bars"]

Well, that's a disappointment. V seems to be defaulted to "Show Monster Health Bars". More of a nuisance, really, than anything else, but I prefer there to be less blinking in my game than Christmas lights.

I didn't see any straightforward instructions on how to unbind a key, so I played with it a bit. Backspace failed. Esc failed. Right click and middle click failed too. I suppose I could bind it to some out-of-the-way key, but I prefer to just unbind it for thoroughness sake.

**How do I completely unbind a key binding?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can unbind a key by binding it to a different action, and then changing the key for that other action a second time.

Taking your case as an example, we want <kbd>V</kbd> to be unbound.

We'll start by opening up the keyboard settings and binding "Toggle Inventory Menu" to <kbd>V</kbd> instead of the default <kbd>I</kbd>.

You'll see a message at the bottom of the keybindings window stating that "Show Player Health Bars is Now Unbound!"

Now that "Show Player Health Bars" is no longer bound to <kbd>V</kbd>, change "Toggle Inventory Menu" back to using <kbd>I</kbd>.

Now <kbd>V</kbd> is no longer bound to any Diablo 3 function, and is free to use as your push-to-talk key.

These steps are also useful if you find yourself accidentally pressing keys like "show/hide party" and wondering why you can't see anyone on the minimap, and want to make sure you can't accidentally turn it off in the future.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is by hovering your mouse over the bind you wish to remove, then pressing the <kbd>Del</kbd> key.

Comment: Good to know. This is probably the better way -- *if* you know what command the key is bound to and where to find it in the long, long list of key bindings...or if you're looking through the list of key bindings and turning off the ones that sound like a bad idea (like show/hide party). If you're looking to free up a push-to-talk key that's taken by something you'd never use, and don't want to bother finding the command that uses the key you want to free up, it's probably easier to re-assign some other command to overwrite it, and then set that command back to its default.

Comment: this is the best way of doing it