# How to disable F keys? (F1-F9)

Tags: diablo-iii, keyboard

Specifically the <kbd>F9</kbd> key.  I use the <kbd>F9</kbd> key bound to a mouse button to talk in Teamspeak since it has little interference with most games.

Diablo 3 has <kbd>F9</kbd> bound to open the achievements menu and there is no key binding setting for it.  How can I disable this key while in-game?

Comment: So on a certain mouseclick you actually use the F9 button which in turn is the push to talk button in teamspeak? Why don't you just bind the mouseclick as push to talk?

Comment: I use a Razer Naga Epic for my gaming and the key I use is "12" on the mouse.  Without any rebinding, I'd be pressing and holding "=" every time I wanted to talk.  So I just bind it to a key almost no game uses (or disable it if it is a keybind for that game).

Comment: f9 is actually quickload in a huge number of games, but probably not functional in MP games.

Comment: Right.  When I play single player games like Fallout / Elder Scrolls I am not in Teamspeak anyway.  I am strictly talking about multiplayer here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

F9 is actually a configurable keybind...you just seem to have missed it.  Observe:

[image: Keybinds screen]

To clear a keybinding, see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68055/how-do-i-tell-diablo-3-i-no-longer-want-a-key-binding?rq=1).

Comment: Ah ha! I wasn't even looking at the row on the right.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Those freehand circles tho!