# How can I restore the skip functionality of the space key?

Tags: diablo-iii

Recently, when I was playing around with new hotkey settings for Diablo 3, I bound several keys to new functions, inkluding the space key. 
I then found out, that because of the new space key function, I could no longer skip dialogs with space, so I unbound the space key (like described [in this Arqade question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68055/how-do-i-tell-diablo-3-i-no-longer-want-a-key-binding)).

Unfortunately, the skip function still didn't work. I tried binding space to other functions and then unbind space, but it still didn't work.

How do I get the skip dialog functionality of the space key back?

Comment: In that screenshot in that question you see that space is bound to "Close All Open Windows". I think that is the default binding and maybe it's linked to skipping dialogs

Comment: Ah! It seems you are right. Just tested it and it works. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that screenshot in that question you see that space is bound to "Close All Open Windows". That is the default binding and it's also linked to skipping dialogs